# Problem with ActiveX C# app

Tags: .net, activex

I'm experiencing weird problem with an visual ActiveX control.

I've created simple test winforms application on .NET 3.5 using that 3rd party ActiveX control. 
It works fine on my dev PC with VS 2008 installed, but when copy it on a machine without VS installed on it, the events from this .OCX don't fire at all. It is a visual OCX, it shows up, but events dont work. If I install VS - it starts working correctly, de-install it - works partially.

What could it be? I do release build, installed C++ redist. packages and no success...

Some details - i use this ActiveX to log in to remote server, call method to retrieve recent data, and need to handle the event returning dozens of strings...

Regards,

Vlado

Comment: No. The code in the eventhandler is not being executed at all. There i just increment static int. It stays 0... With VS it is incrementing.

Comment: try using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to profile the process that runs the OCX, maybe this will reveal a missing dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **Menahem** for the advice! 
I resolved the problem using Process Monitor. The missing library was stdole.dll.

Comment: Great to hear it is sorted. You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.